# Statistics facebook like

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

On a webpage i have facebook like button and facebook comments.
I try to find statistics about the percentage of people who liked / let a comment by phone or computer. I did not find anything but peraphs somebody can show me the good way ?

thanks !

Comment: You might want to look into Domain Insights. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/platforminsights/domains

Comment: So sad i had a -1 for this... But yeah it's the good answer. It well hiden but it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into Domain Insights.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/platforminsights/domains

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing in the Graph API. If you want to use something like this, you'll have to build this on your own.